# CSS and Images not displaying while converting HTML to PDF in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

I am new to CodeIgniter, trying to convert HTML to PDF. Text is almost same in both `html_page_output` and `pdf_output`  but CSS and images are not working in PDF.

My **controller code** is like this:

```
$html = $this->load->view('searching/pdfShow', $data,true);
$this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
$this->dompdf->load_html($html);
$this->dompdf->render();
$this->dompdf->stream("welcome.pdf");
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the URLs you have in src attribute. It most likely should be absolute, not like "/images/foo/bar.png" but "http://yourdomain.com/images/foo/bar.png"

Comment: i am using the image path like this <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/logo.png" />

Comment: anyway, check the real URL you're getting there. Disable streaming, just check $html variable content